# Set dropdown to default value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown on my html page, when it is first loaded, it is set to a default value. But when a user changes the value, I'm checking the selected value against another text field. If the condition does not satisfy, I want to show an alert to the user and reset the dropdown.

I'm able to show the alert with my condition, but how do I reset the dropdown after showing an alert to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
document.getElementById("#dropdownId").selectedIndex = 0
```